# How are the python range class instance attributes readonly?

Tags: python, class, range, built-in

The built-in range class of python has the following behavior

```
x = range(1)
x.step = 10
AttributeError: 'range' object attribute 'step' is read-only
```

Now I am aware we can get this behavior by using @property decorator. But for the property decorator to work it must reference another attribute/method of the instance.

In an instance of the range class I don't see any other method or dunder(double under) or under attribute which holds the value step.

How is this achieved. Is this possible to achieve without @property in pure python or is this the case as range in a build in class implemented in C and not in pure python.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `__setattr__` to raise an error if you attempt to set `step`.

```
class range:
    __slots__ = ['step']

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr == "step":
            raise AttributeError("'range' object attribute 'step' is read-only")
```

The definition of `__slots__` prevents you from trying something like `x.__dict__['step'] = 10`.

Comment: this doesn't work well, as i can never initialize step in `__init__`,
I need it to be read only once initialized

Comment: You can bypass `range.__setattr__` with something like `super().__setattr__('step', step)`.  That does suggest this isn't 100% solid, but there will *always* be things you can do via C in CPython that you can't in pure Python, simply because CPython is what *defines* what you can do in Python. Whatever limits CPython places on you can always be ignored by CPyhton itself.